# Using Nginx and apache on the same system

Tags: php, apache-2.2, nginx

I am using apache server on ubuntu 11.04. I came to know about Nginx server which has some good features.

So I decided to have a ride on it. But I am little bit confused as I have already installed apache and again I will install Nginx may they conflict each other?

But I came to know that as they both server use different ports so then I can use them.

So my question is how to configure both so that Nginx will not conflict with the www folder where all the projects resides and runs by apache.

Answer (score 3):

Change `listen 80;` in your nginx config to the port that you'd like to use.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to Shane's answer, if your server has multiple network cards, you could have each listen on a separate ip address.

Comment: You don't necessarily need multiple NICs. You can bind multiple addresses to a single interface: http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_One_Interface

Comment: @Gerald Yes, you're quite right.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to this question:

1. What IP address and port number [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#Listen) and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#listen) listen on. Both use the *Listen* directive for this.
2. What directory [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#DocumentRoot) and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#root) serve files from. Apache uses *DocumentRoot* for this, Nginx uses *Root*.